# Instant notification on Facebook message

Tags: facebook, if-this-then-that

I want to receive a mail whenever a new message on Facebook is received. Well, that works, but it delivers only after 30 minutes. So, is there a Facebook setting that would let me get the message instantly?

I thought IFTTT would have such feature, but they don't. Maybe Facebook does have a setting for the time, but I can't see it.

Comment: I edited your question to remove the app recommendation part, as it was in violation of the site’s scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no setting for Mail that will allow you to receive the message instantly.
The only other option will be to download one of Facebook native apps for a phone you own.

Other alternatives outside the scope of this site will be to use programming with the Facebook API.